# Show $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}dt$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

How could I show $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}dt=\infty?$$

I tried to use comparison test so that $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}\geq \dfrac{C}{t},$$ for some $C$, and we can use the fact that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{t}dt=\infty$$ to conclude, but this requires me to find a $C$ such that $$1+t^{2}\leq\dfrac{1}{C^{2}}t^{2},$$ which is $$\dfrac{1-C^{2}}{C^{2}}t^{2}\geq 1$$ for all $t$.

How could I find such value?

Thank you!

Comment: Try $\sqrt{1+t^2} \le 1+t$. $t \mapsto {1 \over t+k}$ is not integrable either.

Comment: @copper.hat this only happens if $t\geq 0$, right?

Comment: @copper.hat oh, i can restrict it to $t\geq a$, for some $a$.

Comment: Yes, make it $|t|$ instead if you want, or restrict to $t \ge 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat yes, you are right. thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the integrand is positive, it suffices to show the tail $\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} \, dt$ diverges for some $a$.
Then you can note that $\sqrt{1+t^2} \le 2t$ for $t \ge 1$, for instance.

Comment: oh I forgot about I can only show for $t\geq a$, thank you.

Comment: so $a$ can be any number or $a$ has to be positive? and is it because integrand being positive or even?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Because the integrand is positive, the integral over $\mathbb{R}$ (if it exists) will be at least as large as the integral over $(a, \infty)$ for any $a$.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Its antiderivative is known:
$$\int\!\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\operatorname{argsinh}t=\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2+1}).$$

Comment: argsinh? You mean arsinh?

Comment: I stick to the old name (actually, I should have written $\operatorname{argsh}$). Semantically, it means ‘argument with hyperbolic sine equal to $t$’.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that was used in English. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2):

From $\sqrt{1+t^2}\gt|t|$ we have

$$\int_\mathbb{R}{1\over\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt\gt\int_0^\infty{t\over1+t^2}\,dt={1\over2}\ln(1+t^2)\big|_0^\infty=\infty$$

Comment: I really hope you didn't get mad at me for not accepting your answer. I hope you will accept my positive votes.